# Can't get the grid system to work in Comfortable Mexican Sofa

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I'm building a page using Comfortable Mexican Sofa and for some reason the grid class isn't working.

I'll assign a div with the class=span6 but when I inspect it none of the bootstrap css is applied.

```
.row
.span6
    %a#pain-assessment{:href => "pain_assessment"}
        .circle
            %div PAIN ASSESSMENT

        %input#audit-link.btn.btn-primary.submit{:type => "submit", :name => "planning-link", :value => "Start planning"}/

        %p#audit-text Some description of the Pain Assessment Track - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ac ullamcorper lorem, vitae facilisis tellus.

.span6
    %a#pain-management{:href => "pain_management"}
        .circle
            %div PAIN MANAGEMENT

        %input#audit-link.btn.btn-primary.submit{:type => "submit", :name => "planning-link", :value => "Start Planning"}/

        %p#audit-text Some description of the Pain Management Track - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ac ullamcorper lorem, vitae facilisis tellus.
```

The annoying thing is that when I put the code into jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/9hfwao9y/1/) it does what I want it to... which makes me assume it has got to be a CMS issue.

Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: These names are getting ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

Ok so just in case this ever come up for someone else, it was simply a case of using depreciated code in bootstrap. You should be using

```
col-md-6
```

instead of

```
span6
```